# How to fail/exit execution of a golang program when environment variable not found?

Tags: go

I need to read an environment variable `SubscriptionID` to golang-variable `subId`. My program works well when it can read env variable `SubscriptionID`. Program runs to completion **even it can't find env var** & produces unexpected result.

How to make it fail(exit execution) if it can't find an environment variable?

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
)

func main(){
  subId := os.Getenv("SubscriptionID")
  fmt.Printf("SubscriptionID: %v\n", subId)
}
```

Comment: check if `subId==""` and exit if it is so?

Comment: @BurakSerdar: That test is true if it is present but empty. OP asked: "How to make it fail(exit execution) if it can't find an environment variable?"

Comment: If the program produces unexpected if the variable isn't set (making Getenv return the empty string), wouldn't it also produce unexpected results if SubscriptionID is set to the empty string explicitly?

Comment: @Peter, didn't thought about that. That would be a good test case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [Package os](https://golang.org/pkg/os/)
>
> ```
> import "os"
> ```
>
> [func LookupEnv](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#LookupEnv)
>
> ```
> func LookupEnv(key string) (string, bool)
> ```
>
> LookupEnv retrieves the value of the environment variable named by the
>   key. If the variable is present in the environment the value (which
>   may be empty) is returned and the boolean is true. Otherwise the
>   returned value will be empty and the boolean will be false.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    subId, present := os.LookupEnv("SubscriptionID")
    if !present {
        fmt.Printf("SubscriptionID: not present\n")
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("SubscriptionID: %v\n", subId)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/t-HAS0zC3M7

Output:

```
SubscriptionID: not present
```